# Why Tailwind renders later than Mantine in Next 13 using the new app routing?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, mantine

I am building a project based on the new Next app routing. First, the Mantine components were not rendered properly on the page, only after a few seconds when client side rendering happened.
I have added the following code based on what I found:

```
'use client';

import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import { useEmotionCache, MantineProvider } from '@mantine/core';
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';

export default function RootStyleRegistry({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const cache = useEmotionCache();
    cache.compat = true;

    useServerInsertedHTML(() => (
        <style
            data-emotion={`${cache.key} ${Object.keys(cache.inserted).join(' ')}`}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: Object.values(cache.inserted).join(' '),
            }}
        />
    ));

    return (
        <CacheProvider value={cache}>
            <MantineProvider withGlobalStyles withNormalizeCSS>
                {children}
            </MantineProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
    );
}
```

This has solved the problem, and I have the Mantine components at first rendering, however for additional styling I am using Tailwind, and now at first rendering the page shows the original Mantine styling, and after a few second loads the Tailwind styles. The page flickers, colors are changing, you can imagine.

This is how my basic layout.tsx file looks like:

```
import RootStyleRegistry from './emotion';
import './globals.css';

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en-US">
      <head />
        <body className='bg-primary-0 text-secondary-3'>
          <RootStyleRegistry>{children}</RootStyleRegistry>
        </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I was spending a lot of time already finding a solution for this, but I did not see anyone else having similar issue. If anyone can help and enlighten me what I might be doing wrong, that would be great!

Let me know if you need more context!

Comment: Does this still happen when you run `yarn build && yarn start`? This is most likely a development only issue.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I have checked in the build version as well, the tailwind styles load fairly quickly, almost cannot see the change. Some components still flicker, but I see that will be my useEffect, so that's an entirely other issue. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answer, but it might help someone else who might also face this issue.

You can find the solution [here](https://github.com/orgs/mantinedev/discussions/1672#discussioncomment-5987110)

Basically we need to add the tailwind base to a layer in css *(this reduces the priority of the import)* in your global.css (or wherever you have imported the tailwindcss)

```
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer tailwind {
  @tailwind base;
}

/* if you have any mantine imports, you can include that here as well */
@import "@mantine/core/styles.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sesha answered you need to wrap your Tailwind reset styles.
And you need to add `.layer` to your Mantine styles import.

```css
@layer tailwind {
  @tailwind base;
}

import '@mantine/core/styles.layer.css';
import '@mantine/dates/styles.layer.css';
```

I had a different problem win Mantine and Tailwind, but Google leads here so I'll answer here.
I had Mantine having greater importance than tailwind styles.
I wanted to override Mantine styles with Tailwind styles. This is how things supposed to be.

https://mantine.dev/styles/mantine-styles/

> Some bundlers and frameworks do not allow you to control the order of stylesheets in your application. For example, Next.js does not guarantee styles import order. In this case, you can use CSS layers to ensure that your styles will always override Mantine styles.

This way we have base Mantine styles and can fully customize them with Tailwind.